# An ultraweakly continuous functional on the unit ball is ultraweakly continuous everywhere.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Given a von Neumann Algebra $\mathcal{M} \subset \mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$, one defines a normal linear functional on $\mathcal{M}$ to be an ultraweakly continuous linear functional. Usually it's proven that this property is equivalent to preserving suprema of bounded increasing nets/being completely additive. However, it is important to know that $\varphi:\mathcal{M} \to \mathbb{C}$ is ultraweakly continuous on $\mathcal{M}$ iff it is only ultraweakly continuous on the unit ball of $\mathcal{M}$ (e.g. in proving that the set of normal functionals is a Banach space). **I couldn't figure out a proof of this fact, the literature somehow ignores it/considers it as trivial. Any reference/clear proof will be greatly appreciated.**

This of course can't be true for the usual WOT topology (on the unit ball continuity in both is the same), but in all attempts of proving this fact I didn't see a difference between using WOT and the ultraweak topology, so I couldn't devise a full proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a_\alpha$ be a bounded positive increasing net with least upper bound $a$. Then $a_\alpha\to a$ in the ultra-strong topology, which is stronger than the ultra-weak toplogy hence $a_\alpha\to a$ ultra-weakly. It sounds like you know this statement, but if you do not you can consult Lemma 2.4.19. in the book by Bratteli and Robinson.

Note then that $a_\alpha/(2\|a\|)$ is contained entirely in the unit ball and it converges to $a/(2\|a\|)$ which is also contained in the unit ball. As such if $\varphi$ is ultra-weakly continuous on the unit ball you get that:
$$\varphi(a_\alpha)  = 2\|a\|\,\varphi(a_\alpha/(2\|a\|) \,)\to 2\|a\| \,\varphi(a/(2\|a\|)\,) = \varphi(a),$$
so $\varphi$ preserves suprema of bounded positive nets, hence is normal. (You did not include "positivity" in your formulation, but if this bothers you then changing the net to $\sup_\alpha\|a_\alpha\|\Bbb1 - (a-a_\alpha)$ is a way to make a bounded increasing net into a bounded increasing positive net.)

Comment: I see, that explains it if I can prove preserving suprema implies normality. Thanks! I haven't gone through all proofs of this fact yet, but as far as I know, it uses the fact that the set of normal functionals is operator norm closed (a Banach space). The proof I saw for this fact ((in Cyril Houdayer's notes) uses the statement I originally asked about. Do you happen to have a preferred proof of this fact (that the predual is a Banach space)?

Comment: I'm not an expert on von Neumann algebras. But Theorem 2.4.21. of Bratteli and Robinson shows that normal states are the same as ultra-weakly continuous states. And in Murphy's book Theorems 2.4.9., 2.4.10. and their preceding discussion explain why the ultra-weak functionals are a predual (which in this construction is Banach as a quotient of a Banach space by a closed subspace).

Comment: Thanks for the references!